# On godaddy server frontend not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, server

Backend is working fine but front end only default controller working if i call default controller writing name of controller and function then its not working

> (giving 404 error "indialive_today/home/ was not found on this server.")

`.htaccess`

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /demo/indialive_today
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L]
    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

routes.php

```
$usertype=explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);   
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
    $db =& DB();
    $query = $db->get( 'news' );
    $result = $query->result();  
if($usertype[3] == ''){ $route['default_controller'] = "home/index"; }
 else if($usertype[3] != ''){ foreach( $result as $row ){$route[$row->slug] = 'news_detail';    }
}
```

Comment: As I know godaddy shared server does not allow your local .httacess file.You can ask them to resolve it.Or you can use your url using /index.php/

Comment: Do your application work if you include index.php in the URL?

Comment: backend working fine problem on front end

Comment: Do your application work if you include index.php in the URL?

Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

From post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330398/codeigniter-and-godaddy-default-controller-issues

Answer (score 0):

In your file, you have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

See the question mark? That means you are passing the request to the query string (`QUERY_STRING`). However, you are checking for a request URI (`REQUEST_URI`).

So, first, you need to change that line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

An even better option would be to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You also need to add a forward slash to your `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteBase /thinksoft/demo/indialive_today/
```

After some optimisations, your file (which should exist in the `/thinksoft/demo/indialive_today/` directory) should look like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

    # If you are using Apache 2.4.4 and later you can uncomment
    # the line below, which is a decent alternative for using
    # mod_rewrite
    # FallbackResource /thinksoft/demo/indialive_today/index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /thinksoft/demo/indialive_today/

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php/$1 [L]

    # When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    # This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    # Submitted by: Fabdrol
    # Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    # or use the following as a replacement to the rule above:
    # RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** I have also added the [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) option (commented out), which can be quite useful.

Also make sure that your CodeIgniter configuration is set to use `REQUEST_URI` and not `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: same issue only default controller working

if i write controller name in address bar its gives 404 error on frontend but working fine on backend

Comment: Are you getting an Apache 404 or a CI 404?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /thinksoft/demo/indialive_today/news1 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at www.thinksoftsolutions.com Port 80

Comment: It's your `RewriteBase` that is wrong - you didn't mention before that `thinksoft` is also part of the URI. Answer updated.